# Almost correct answer not fixed

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I had [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400057/getting-the-name-of-the-makefile-from-the-makefile/1400184#1400184) on SO, and there is an almost correct answer posted. I made a comment on the answer that I will accept it when it is fixed. It was 11 days ago and it seems that the author of the answer will not come back to fix his question. What should the OP (me) do in a case like this?

1. Accept the almost correct answer.
2. Post a new answer that is correct and accept it.
3. Wait and hope that the author of the answer will come back.
4. Write an email to the author.
5. Get someone with a high rep to fix the answer.

Comment: You might want to fix the title of your post.

Comment: Chris already fixed it :)

Comment: Maybe the person who answered was being a jerk thinking he didn't need to fix his answer.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case (it's a minor edit), I would accept it. Your comment describes what has to be fixed. After posting it here on MSO, some highrep SO user will care about it soon.

[Sinan Ünür](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100754/sinan-unur) cared about it.

Comment: Thanks for both Sinan and John.